# What is the timezone in mysql curdate() function

Tags: mysql

MySQL curdate() returns the current date. I want to know the timezone. 
Whether returned date is in GMT or UTC or IST(my local machines timezone).

MySQL server is running on my local machine.

I ran this command on "22 Jan 2015" in India. And mysql output is

```
mysql> select curdate();
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
| 2015-01-22 | 
+------------+
```

At this moment both IST and UTC are on same date. UTC is 22 Jan 2015 7:31 am and IST 22 Jan 2015 1:01 pm

Comment: so... what gives `CURDATE()` when you run it? might hint you on the timezone

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I am not sure about timezone. At this moment both IST and UTC are on same date. UTC is 22 Jan 2015 7:31 am and IST 22 Jan 2015 1:01 pm

Comment: `select curdate();` returns the date _in_ the timezone that is defined for your connection. You can check this by doing something like this:  `SET time_zone ='-12.00';select curdate();`.

Comment: @t.niese you comment helped. Thanks its local timezone. System's zone to be exact.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would guess that you got the downvote for not doing a research yourself. e.g. a search for `CURDATE timezone` would give you a linke to [MSQL: Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and there they write : `[...]The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIME(), CURRENT_DATE(), and FROM_UNIXTIME() functions return values in the connection's current time zone, which is available as the value of the time_zone system variable.[...]` (`[...]CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE() are synonyms for CURDATE().`)

Comment: @t.niese you are right. I will follow it from next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

if word "SYSTEM" in output is not enough, you can use:

```
   SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
```

This get time shift from you time to UTC.

Answer (score 3):

This query returns the timezone of the current session

```
select timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'));
```